# How do I use jQuery to preventDefault behaviour on a form after the DOM has loaded?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm loading a form using jQuery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('button').click(function(){
                $url="/quiz/" + $(this).attr('id');
                $.ajax({
                    url:$url,
                    success:function(data){
                        $('button').fadeOut('slow',function(){
                            $('.center').html(data).hide().fadeIn(600);
                        });

                    }
                });
            });

$(document).on('submit','form-inline', function(event){
        alert("Attempt");
        event.preventDefualt();
    });

</script>
```

With the markup:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Quiz Name">
  <button id="quiz-name" type="submit" class="btn btn-large">Next >></button>
</form>
```

After the form has loaded I would like to prevent the form from submitting. But I'm having difficulty emulating this behaviour. How would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).on('submit','form-inline', function(event){
```

should point to a class:

```
$(document).on('submit','.form-inline', function(event){
```

Also, you misspelled `.preventDefault`.

Comment: That got the alert to show but the button still seems to submit the form.

Comment: Thanks. It's always the little things.

Comment: it wouldn't have notified him if it is instantly posting, :-p well, it would have but it wouldn't have been obvious to see.